# Shelf Life of Gochujang

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, food-science, storage-lifetime, food-preservation

I made Korean Gochujang with the following ingredients: Fermented White Miso Paste, Gochugaru (Fine powdered chili flakes), Sugar, Water, Salt and Vinegar. I cooked all ingredients except for the salt and vinegar which I added after the mixture almost boiled. I will be giving this away to my family and friends who live far away. Shipping will be around 1-2 weeks. My questions is how long will it last specially if they don't have access to refrigerators?

Comment: Hi, you might need to read up on how food safety rules work, see our writeup under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. Basically, you either made a recipe for which the author proved that it is shelf stable, or you have to throw it out after 3-5 days, the food safety rules don't recognize anything in between.

Comment: As @rumtscho stated. Third option is, you get your product tested for a shelf life. You are either making intermediate product, for finishing a meal or just a meal (following basic food safety rules). If it is product per se, you follow different food safety guidelines and have license for that. Otherwise, you follow basic food safety rules. No one sane would want to recommend you shelf life according to a method, its a hazard.